# Ruby: What is it declare in a class?

Tags: ruby

I got this sample code from datamapper http://datamapper.org/getting-started.html

```
class Post
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,         Serial    # An auto-increment integer key
  property :title,      String    # A varchar type string, for short strings
  property :body,       Text      # A text block, for longer string data.
  property :created_at, DateTime  # A DateTime, for any date you might like.
end
```

Can anyone tell me that how "property" generate? Is it a function, variable, class variable or instance variable or a constant?

sometime i also saw this kind of code

```
class CarModel
   attribute :name
   attribute :hello
end
```

but no idea how does this generate

Comment: I think you may be meaning something other than "how xxx generate". `property` is a method, as is `attribute`. Both are being called/invoked within the class definition. What they "do" is a separate question.

Comment: so are they a method bening invoked every thing when class is initialized?

Comment: is there any name of how this pattern they called?

Comment: `property :id, Serial` is just call of function with 2 arguments. It changes class (adds property). It's meta-programming tip. Ruby has a lot of it.

Answer (score 1):

It is a method that is included when you do:

```
include DataMapper::Resource
```

You can see its source code [here](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/blob/master/lib/dm-core/model/property.rb#L42) if you're interested in digging in deeper.

It basically adds a property to the list of properties in your `Post` resource.

Comment: so property function will be executed when we initialize the class?

Comment: Yes, it is called when the class is initialised (when its source code is loaded). Also Ruby does not have functions, it is a method.

Comment: @KitHo Don't confuse "when class is initialized" with "when an instance of the class is created". `property` and `attribute` are only called once per their occurrence in the code - when the class itself is defined/initialized.

Comment: Is there any name for this kind of pattern , so that i can search more on google. I never find this pattern in java/c++ code before